# Mac Os x and xcode versions for ipod 3.1.3

Tags: xcode, macos, ipod

Thanks in advance .

I have an ipod 3.1.3. If i want to develope an app for ipod3.1.3 then which os version of mac and xcode i need to install in my mac .If any one know please tell to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop the app using the current versions of OS X and Xcode, which includes the iOS 4 SDK. In the Build Rules for your app, you would set the Deployment Target to 3.1 or lower.

Comment: My mac os x is 10.6.5 and xcode is 3.2.5 i kept target platform ios 3.1.3 for ipod but it is giving "A valid provisioningprofilefor this executable was not found."

Comment: Have you enabled the iPod for development in Xcode, do you have membership of the iOS development program, have you downloaded your code signing certificate from the Apple provisioning portal?

Comment: The Problam was solved. Thank U ,yes i have registered my ipod and have downloaded code signing certificate from the Apple provisioning portal.Once again Thanks for ur response.